# SharePoint Workflow: Standard vs Enterprise

Tags: 2013, workflow, enterprise, standard, license

I've started at a new company recently and I've heard some people from other business units say that one of the reasons they chose Enterprise license CALs over Standard is "you can do more with SharePoint workflows".

This surprised me, and was the first time I heard or read this any where.

Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could see this holding water is if they are referring to workflows revolving around publishing. Foundation, Standard, and Enterprise all run the same workflow engine and have access to the same actions.

Comment: That's exactly what I thought Eric. You have me intrigued on your "workflows revolving around publishing" comment. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Thinking about it more, things in the publishing space would follow the same workflow process that a document library with check in/check out, major/minor versioning, and requiring content approval. So there is really no reason from a workflow perspective why you would buy enterprise over standard. There are a slew of other features in Enterprise that are worth the upgrade, but workflow is not one of them.

Comment: This answers my question. I have a feeling the people I heard this from might have been referring to Nintex Workflow, which I understand does offer additional workflow activities with its enterprise license offering.

Comment: Yes, there is a night and day difference between Nintex Standard and Enterprise.